# Client Facing REST API Authentication

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

I have seen many different posts regarding different solutions for authenticating a RESTful API and I have some questions, given this current scenario.

I've built a REST API that will allow clients of my software service (we are a B2B company) to access resources programmatically.  Now that I've got the API working properly, I'd like to secure it in the most standardized way possible.  I need to allow access to certain resources based on the caller of the API.  That is to say, not all users of the API can access all resources.

I have URLS available in the following formats:

```
https://mydomain/api/students
https://mydomain/api/students/s123
https://mydomain/api/students/s123/classes
https://mydomain/api/students/s123/classes/c456
```

So far I've come up with these possible solutions:

1. Provide a unique key to each client that they can use to ultimately generate an encrypted token that will be passed as a GET parameter at the end of each REST call to (re)-authenticate every single request.  Is this approach too expensive

   https://mydomain.com/api/students/s123?token=abc123
2. Provide a value in the HTTP Authorization Header as seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). Is this almost the same as #1? (Except I can't paste a URL into the browser) Do people use these headers anymore?
3. Use OAuth 2 (which I'm still a bit unclear on).  Does OAuth 2 actually authenticate the client as a logged in user? And doesn't that go against the spirit of a REST API being stateless? I was hoping OAuth was the proper solution for me (since it's a public standard), but after reading up on it a little bit, I'm not so sure.  Is it overkill and/or improper for REST API calls?

My goal is to provide an API that will not have to be changed for each client that wants to consume the API, but rather that I can provide a standard documentation made available to all of our clients.

I'll be happy to post additional details if I've been unclear.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 type of clients you probably want to prepare your API:

- trusted clients - Which are written by you. They can have the username and password of the actual user, and they can send that data to your server with every request, possibly in a HTTP auth header. All you need is an encrypted connection by them.
- 3rd party clients - Which are written by some random developer. You can register them in your service and add a unique API key to each of them. After that if an user wants to use their services, you have to show her a prompt in which she can allow access to the 3rd party client. After that the 3rd party client will be assigned to the user's account with the given permissions and it will get an user specific access token. So when the client sends its API key and the user specific token along with the request, then it sends the requests in the name of the user.

OAuth can help you to control the second situation.

Your URLs do not have a meaning to the clients. By REST you have to decouple the clients from the URL structure by sending links annotated with semantics (e.g. link relations). So your documentation does not have to contain anything about the URL structure (maybe it can be useful for server side debug, but nothing more). You have to talk about different types of links. By generating these links on server side, you can check the permissions of the actual user (or 3rd party client) and skip the links which she does not have permission to follow.